# how can we checkIn a new folder with files and subfiles into TFS using TF commands?

Tags: shell, powershell, tfs, tf-cli

i want to map and checkIn a local folder which contains files into TFS using power shell scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence would be:

> **`tf workspace /new`** (Create a new workspace)
>
> **`tf workfold /map`** and **`tf workfold /cloak`** (Map server folders to local folders)
>
> **`tf get`** (optional to get the contents of the server folder)
>
> **`tf add`** (Add the files/folders to the staging area)
>
> **`tf checkin`** (check in the changes)
>
> **`tf workspace /delete`** (optional to remove the (temporary) workspace)

If you need to merge/resolve conflicts, you can use **`tf resolve`.**

Answer (score 1):

TFS Powershell commandlets are available with [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)

These are available for all versions of TFS. Remember to install the PowerShell cmdlet options.

Once install, you would simply have to add Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Powershell snapin in your script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
```

You can then use the out of the box cmdslets such as Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit and New-TfsChangeset to add items and check-in